# Can I create my own output stream that is different from stdout and stderr?

Tags: shell, stdout, stderr

The UNIX man pages for `unistd.h` states:

```
The following symbolic constants are defined for file streams:
STDIN_FILENO  File number of stdin.  It is 0.
STDOUT_FILENO File number of stdout. It is 1.
STDERR_FILENO File number of stderr. It is 2.
```

grepping all of my header files, I find this to be true.

```
[/usr]grep -r "STDIN_FILENO" include
include/unistd.h:#define    STDIN_FILENO    0   /* Standard input.  */

[/usr] grep -r "STDOUT_FILENO" include 
include/unistd.h:#define    STDOUT_FILENO   1   /* Standard output.  */

[/usr]grep -r "STDERR_FILENO" include
include/boost/asio/detail/impl/handler_tracking.ipp:  ::write(STDERR_FILENO, line, length);
include/unistd.h:#define    STDERR_FILENO   2   /* Standard error output.  */
```

Even though they are defined, they appear to never be used by any other std header file on my machine.  I find that strange.  Perhaps 0,1, and 2 are used elsewhere instead of the defined macros.  The macros just exist to be referenced as an indication of how the streams are configured..?

Anyway, we can capture particular output streams in the shell by doing this:

```
./program 1> stdout.txt
./program 2> stderr.txt
./program > both.txt 2>&1
```

I want to create my own output stream, and capture it by doing this:

```
./program 3> mine.txt
```

I tried searching around `unistd.h` and other files included by `<iostream>` to see how `std::cout` and `std::cerr` worked, but as you might imagine, I got lost and confused.

I'm more interested in whether you can do this, not whether it's a good idea.

Comment: Take a look at the Bash documentation. The file descriptors are inherited from the login or terminal program by bash, and then inherited by your program.

Comment: If you are using GCC you may find use for their non-standard library: `<ext/stdio_filebuf.h>` which allows you to create a `std::filebuf` (and therefor a `std::fstream`) from a POSIX file descriptor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open file descriptors are inherited by child processes.  The operating system takes care of connecting a process with the three standard streams, but you are free to do any number of [`open()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open)s followed by an [`exec()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec)  (preferably after a previous [`fork()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)).  The child can then scan the list of open file descriptors (in `/proc/self/fd/`) or somehow “know” which ones to use.

Here is a small example written in C.

```c
#include <errno.h>   /* errno                        */
#include <stdio.h>   /* atoi, fprintf                */
#include <stdlib.h>  /* EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE   */
#include <string.h>  /* strerror, strlen             */
#include <unistd.h>  /* write                        */

static const char *const message = "hello, world\n";

int main(int argc, char * * argv)
{
  int fd;
  int i;
  for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
      fd = atoi(argv[i]);
      if (write(fd, message, strlen(message)) < 0)
        {
          fprintf(stderr, "error: cannot write to fd %d: %s\n",
                  fd, strerror(errno));
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The caller of the program is responsible for opening any file descriptors the program should write to and tell it so via its command line arguments.

To pass it the open file descriptor 3 that is connected to the file `redir`, we can use the [`exec`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/exec) utility of the shell to open the file descriptors and execute the child.

```
$ exec 3>redir ./a.out 3
```

This will close the current shell after the child exits, so you probably want to try it in a subshell:

```
$ sh -c 'exec 3>redir ./a.out 3'
```

Or, alternatively, don't use `exec` but the redirection syntax @[bmargulies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131433/bmargulies) mentioned.  Here, we are writing to standard error output (2), as well as to the file descriptors 3 and 4 where we redirect 3 to standard output (1) and 4 to the file `redir`.

```
$ ./a.out 2 3 4 3>&1 4>redir
hello, world
hello, world
$ cat redir
hello, world
```

Such inheriting of file descriptors is used heavily in server processes that let their (unprivileged) children have file descriptors to log files, files outside their [`chroot()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chroot) jail, TCP connections and what not else.

Unfortunately, forgetting to close a file descriptor before `exec()`uting a child process is a common bug that can be security relevant.  There is a [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) module to check this.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `open`, it returns a number. You pass that number to `read` and `write`. You can, however, run a command like:

```
mycommand 3 3>bloop.txt
```

And inside mycommand, convert argv[1] to a number, and pass it to write.

Comment: Ah, the first parameter of this function. The file descriptor(fd)
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html